# Effective exapsnion of Brans-Dicke like gravity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, effective-field-theory, modified-gravity

I'm working on the effects of higher derivative terms in gravitational theories and I have a question based on the effective expansion of a Brans-Dicke-like theory. Essentially my question is, in my expansion can I have terms that cross with the scalar gravitational field?. I.e. in the case of a $\psi^4$ matter theory, can I have terms such as

$$\frac{\phi^4\psi^2}{\Lambda^2}+\frac{(\partial_\mu\psi)^2\phi^2}{\Lambda^2}+\cdots$$

or can I only expand the matter part of the Lagragian?

For example, if I write the Lagrangian for a normal Brans-Dicke theory we have,
$$\mathcal{L}=\phi R-\frac{\omega}{\phi}g^{\mu\nu}\phi_{,\mu}\phi_{,\nu}+\mathcal{L}_{matter},$$
in the Jordan frame. In the Jordan frame the matter Lagrangian has no explicit dependence on the scalar field $\phi$ until we transform into the Einstein frame. So, if I start in the Jordan frame can take the matter Lagrangian expansion ONLY and then transform to the Einstein frame in order to get the $\phi$ dependence or should I just start in the Einstein frame and just perform the expansion?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what it is that you're asking. Anyway, an EFT expansion will contain all kinds of terms, consistent with the theory's symmetries. It is possible that fields of different types mix.

Comment: I'm asking if the scalar/dilation/radion part of the theory is part of the EFT. The problem I'm facing is that EFTs of Brans Dicke type gravity (excluding Galileons) introduce the Ostrogadsky instability, which isn't very nice.